# In MacOS X is there a way to create a shortcut to a folder on a readonly drive?

Tags: macos, mac, alias, hard-drive, read-only

I have a partitioned drive with a different OS on my Mac. I can access this drive in readonly mode, but not write mode.
There is a folder on this partition drive that I often open, and therefore I would like to create a shortcut to it.
However the option "Make Alias" is not available when I right-click on this folder - probably because Mac aliases add info to their targets in order to keep the aliases up to date (?).

Anyway, is there an alternative way to create a shortcut to this read-only folder? Maybe a command that would just open Finder on this folder ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Make Alias" tries to create the alias alongside the original item, which in this case is on a readonly volume.  You need to create the alias so it's stored on another volume, and the easiest way to do this is by holding <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> as you drag the folder to where you want the alias to be -- that'll make the Finder create an alias instead of copying the folder.

Comment: works on macOS Sierra too!